# Responsive image scaling by the height of the window

Tags: css, image, responsive-design, scale

In the same way that setting an image to:

```
img {max-width: 100%;}
```

Such as in: https://jsfiddle.net/kvp7n29n/10/  ... scales the image proportionally when you make the browser window's *width become smaller*, **How do I get the same scaling effect to happen when the browser's *height becomes smaller***?

The end effect I'm trying to accomplish is just like what you see on many responsive lightboxes, such as this: http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/  .

^^ I'm not necessarily wanting to make the lightbox itself, but notice when you click on a single image demo there, the lightbox comes up with the image, and no matter if you shrink the browser window's *width* or *height*, the image in the lightbox stays proportional while shrinking down.

So how do I get that same proportional scaling effect to happen on that kitten in my jsfiddle above?  .

Answer (score 12):

You can set the max-height and width in vh(viewport height) and vw(viewport width) units. Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kvp7n29n/12/

```
img {
    max-width: 100vw;
    height:auto;
    width:auto;
    max-height:100vh;
}
```